# Title Case a sentence error with algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have to title case a sentence. My algorithm is supposed to work but it doesn't. I'm having some problem with the join function. I can't seem to join the array into a string. Is it some problem with the data type? I've tried to change it up a bit but it didn't work, I don't understand why.

```
function titleCase(str) {
  let newStr = str.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  let all;
  for (let i = 0; i < newStr.length; i++) {
    let capitalize = newStr[i][0].toUpperCase();
  //  console.log(capitalize);
    let rest = newStr[i].slice(1);
  //  console.log(rest);
    all = capitalize.concat(rest);
    all.join(" ");
    console.log(all);

  }
  return all;
// return all.join(" ");
} 

titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

Comment: I'll read it, thank you for pointing it out. I'll ask in a better way next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're working with strings, the only array in your function is `newStr`.

Strings don't have a `join` function.

What you could do is to assign `all` to an array and push the strings that you generate into it. Here is an example:

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  let newStr = str.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  const all = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < newStr.length; i++) {
    let capitalize = newStr[i][0].toUpperCase();
    let rest = newStr[i].slice(1);
    all.push(capitalize.concat(rest));
  }
  return all.join(" ");
} 

const result = titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I thought 'all' was an array but it's actually a string. Thank you for the help, I'll pay more attention when I use arrays and strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use regexp

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  return str.toLowerCase().replace(/[\w']+/g,m=>m.replace(/./,c=>c.toUpperCase()))
} 

console.log( titleCase("I'm a little tea pot") );
```

Comment: I thought about using regex but I don't know much of it so I didn't, but your solution is great. Thank you for the feedback.